# How do I let the user create a custom menu in a node?

Tags: 7, nodes, routes, entities

On all my pages there is a side bar menu acting as a node/page specific menu. Typically I would create an entity reference field and let the user choose menu items that way. Then I'd use a view to display the list the user created. However, this list is unique per page and they user may not want it in order my title or date, they may want it in a specific order.

Is there a module that would allow the user to select x number of pages and specify the order of the items selected?

Comment: I've found this: (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57632/ordering-of-referenced-entity) but the manual option isn't in my 7.x-1.0 release of entity reference

Comment: I thought it might be in the beta but I wasn't able to find the option